# django use function from other views

Tags: python, django

I want to use part of the data from an existing function in another view.py (i am new to Django and python)

for example:

result/view.py

```
def result(request,slug)
    datas = modle.objects.get(slug=slug)
    somecodes...
    return render(request,"result.html",data1,data2,data3,data4)
```

And I want part of the data (ex. data1,data2) to use in another view file, how do I do that?

what I have tired

```
from result.view import result 

   def display_data(request,slug) 
      result_data = result.data1
      print(result_data)
```

Comment: did you try to import the other view?

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly call the views in other views. But you can identify common code and move in separate file.

Step 1: Identify the common logic that you require from the existing function.

Step 2: Create a `helpers.py` file, and move the common existing code in this `helpers.py` file.

```
def common_behaviour(username, slug):
    # do code using username and slug for data1 and data2 here 
    return (data1, data2)
```

Step 3: Now import the common_behaviour method in your `views.py` file as below.

```
from .helpers import common_behaviour
def result(request,slug):
    data1, data2 = common_behaviour(request.user.username, slug)

def some_other_view(request,slug):
    data1, data2 = common_behaviour(request.user.username, slug)
```

Comment: for getting data in the common_behaviour function, I needed request and slug for process, how should i fix that ?

Comment: You can pass parameters in common_behavour method. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I am getting errors, saying matching query does not exist. looks like "request.user.username" has problem

Comment: Yes.. request.user.username was just an example for how you can pass the variable. Feel free to change the variable that you need :)